# Two similar sentences have different behaviour. Is it ok?

Tags: ruby, initialization

Two similar sentences have different behaviour. Is it ok?

Compare:

```
a = 123 unless defined? a
a # => nil
```

but...

```
unless defined? b
  b = 123
end
b # => 123
```

Comment: It's counter-intuitive ; I'd suspect something related to how the first is parsed.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I have to agree, it is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behaviour. Local variables are created and initialized with `nil` before assignment. So this code

```
a = 123 unless defined? a
a # => nil
```

is a rough equivalent of

```
a = nil
a = 123 unless defined? a # `a` is not undefined anymore.
a # => nil
```

Another example (even though `c` is not defined before this line, this code does not throw a `NameError`).

```
c = 2 unless c # => 2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's true. But I think that conditions evaluated first... Where is the exact place `a` being initilized? Right after Ruby found any `=` after `a`?

Comment: Seems like initialization being done right after parsing and before actual code evaluation...